# How to let ansible to use service instead of systemctl?

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible service module to restart a system service. Below is the configuration of ansible file. When I run ansible command I got an error related to systemctl. Since my service is configured to run with service command instead of systemctl, I want ansible to use service command to start my service. Is there a way to configure ansible for that?

```
- name: start cooltoo_storage service
sudo: yes
service:
  name: cooltoo_storage
  state: started
```

I got below error when run systemctl. And I don't want to configure my service to be running with systemctl.

```
Job for cooltoo_storage.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status cooltoo_storage.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting from systemctl? The host `service` will just use systemd/sysvinit based on how the script is configured

Comment: I have added the error message on the post. I know I can configure my service with systemctl but I don't want to do that since there are many other people use the command service as well.

Comment: Did you actually check what the error is?

Comment: I didn't set the systemd service in /etc/systemd/. I think if ansible can work with service instead of systemctl, it will fix the problem right?

Comment: Yes it should. Had a quick look at the service module and if you have systemd installed it will use it. So you will either have to write a systemd service or use `command`/`shell`

Comment: Ok thanks. I think command/shell is probably the only solution for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is ansible 2.2, so above that this should work:

```
- name: start cooltoo_storage service
  sudo: yes
  service:
    name: cooltoo_storage
    state: started
    use: service
```

Basically the default value of 'use' is auto and it uses the system default service manager interface (eg. systemctl). You can override this when you know for sure that the system has 'service' command for example.

Details are found in the docs:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/service_module.html

Comment: Is this correct? `service` module seems ignore `use` option. https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/37590

Comment: @fumiyas I had the same problem and needed to use `sysvinit` to obtain the expected behavior. I have posted an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70353739/4413446

Answer (score 1):

To use the `service` command you need to specify `sysvinit` as the `use` parameter.

```yaml
- name: start cooltoo_storage service
  become: true
  service:
    name: cooltoo_storage
    state: started
    use: sysvinit
```